# Windows 10 apache virtual host config

Tags: apache, laravel-5, server

I'm new to laravel. Using version 5.1. Trying to use laravel app as virtualhost. For this I've changed my `httpd-vhosts.conf` as below

```
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\laraveldev/public"
    ServerName laraveldev
</VirtualHost>
```

Now trying to access the app in browser `laraveldev` or `http://laraveldev` but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also make changes in Hosts file to make it work (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).

Does `localhost:80` works (do you see 'Laravel 5' page)?

Comment: It should be `127.0.0.1` laraveldev  -  also, does 127.0.0.1 or localhost works in the browser? Do you see Laravel 5 start page?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. )